# In python, how to set condition to check which projects are currently active and their end date has not passed?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask

I have a Project model with the following fields:

```
class Project(db.Document):
  project_name = db.StringField(max_length=80, required=True)
  description = db.StringField(max_length=160, required=True)
  start_date = db.DateTimeField(required=True)
  end_date = db.DateTimeField(required=True)
  created = db.DateTimeField()
  status = db.BooleanField(default=False)
  releases = db.ListField(db.ReferenceField(Release))
```

and I am trying to create a route that shows all the active projects only whose status are set to true, and their end date has not being passed.

**UPDATED**

```
@app.route('/search/projects', methods=['GET'])
def search_projects_get():
try:
    proj = Project.objects
    if proj.status is True and proj.end_date < datetime.now():
        return jsonify(proj)

except Exception as e:
    errors.bad_request(repr(e))
```

Can someone please help me complete the logic in my route?

Comment: if proj.status == True and project.end_date < date_now ???? Is that what you are asking?

To get date_now date_now = datetime.datetime.now()

Comment: @E.Serra yes, that's exactly what I was asking. Thank you for the response. I just updated my post above with that condition. However, I don't understand why I am getting this error now `The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.`

Comment: Because you don't have a return for when the if is false, so your function returns the default value None

Comment: Gotcha! Thank you so much.